# Model scope from association method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a scope for future events only, the date of an event is based on the activities date and I have a method in my events model called `end_at` but when trying to create a scope for my controller I am getting

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "end_at" does not exist
```

#### Event model

```
has_many :activities, dependent: :destroy

scope :future_events, -> { where('end_at >= ?', Date.today) }

def end_at
  activities.chronological.last.end_at
end
```

Comment: You can't query with the methods.

Comment: Ah great, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to query by methods. You can do something like this:

```
scope :future_events, lambda {
  joins(activities: :chronological)
    .where('chronologicals.end_at >= ?', Date.today)
}
```

Description:

- in `joins` you put names of associations;
- in `where` you put the real names of tables how they are named in database (they sometimes happen to be different from model's associations names).

This scope is basically saying that you want to return future events, where its activities's chronological's `end_at` attribute is `>= Date.today`.

Comment: Great! I didn't know that. I'm getting a syntax error `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...chronologicals: {'end_at >= ?', Date.today }) }`